# Symfony2 SymBlog tutorial : [Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'c.post = :post_id': Error: Class 'c' is not defined.

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I was following the Symfony2 blog [tutorial part 4](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/extending-the-model-blog-comments.html#data-fixtures-revisited) 
and I encountered this error when I tried to query the post's comments:

```
public function postAction($id) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $post = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Post')->find($id);

    if (!$post) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Blog post.');
    }

    $comments = $em->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('c')
            ->where('c.post = :post_id')
            ->addOrderBy('c.created')
            ->setParameter('postId', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

    return $this->render('BlogBundle:Default:post.html.twig', array(
                'post' => $post,
                'comments' => $comments
    ));
}
```

I get the following error:

> "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 15 near 'c.post = :post_id': Error:
>   Class 'c' is not defined."

Answer (score 0):

The link to the tutorial you gave doesn't work for me so I can't see the context of what your are doing but...

The parameter for createQueryBuilder() is the name of the table so you have a table called 'c'. This seems an odd name for a table.

In your query your should be selecting fields from the table, not selecting the table.

Hope that helps but if you can give a link that works I can better see what you're trying to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

You can not call createQueryBuilder directly on EntityManager because it does not know what c is. This is because you just copy&paste without context and code was invoked inside repository class in tutorial. Not in controller.

Try this

```
$comments = $em->getRepository('BlogBundle:Comment')->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c')
        ->where('c.post = :post_id')
        ->addOrderBy('c.created')
        ->setParameter('postId', $id)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Or add method for fetching comments into PostRepository similarly as in tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You should speify the Entity you need:

```
$comments = $em->createQueryBuilder('c')

            ->from('BlogBundle:Comment', 'c') // I suppose your entity is Comment

            ->select('c')
            ->where('c.post = :post_id')
            ->addOrderBy('c.created')
            ->setParameter('postId', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```